# SQLite database with multi language iOS 6 app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I want my app with 2 languages. I'm using the `localization` to do that in the storyboards, so here it's all ok. The problem is I have a 30 mb's `SQLite` database. Is it possible to do 2 app versions and send them to the app store? (each one with differente languages with the specific DB)

Or is a better option host the DB remotely and then download the version (language X or language Y) after check the `localization`?

Comment: I will go with the 2nd one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`I assume its not same app with different binaries for different app stores`).

I saw somewhere but not able to recollect that there was an unofficial limit of three copies of the same app for localisation reasons.Since Apple released the App Store Review Guidelines, one of them is that developers should not "spam" the app store with multiple versions of the same app with minor changes.

Why don't you merge all your apps(languages) into one and keep it in your server.So that the end-user can download any version(language) of the content they want,and even it will be easier for you to keep your database upto date.

Comment: So... 30 mb isn't too much to download?

Comment: @FabioCardoso...you will faint if u get to know that i am doing one similar app..which uses 48 languages(48 database size is almost 500MB).what you say now? :-)

Comment: wow lol... how do you handle it? you check the localization on the first time that app load and then download the entire DB?

Comment: yes dude...in addition to that i will use one main database which will list out available languages database and then i will give the option to user whichever he wants to download(using GPS i will set the default language according to the country/state)...but the direction is correct..

Comment: Can you provide the code to download the SQLite DB from a server?

Comment: i haven't used any big code to download databases..just give the url and fly...i used AFNetworking(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library..because it gives me alot more option like pausing the download etc...even you can use apple's NSURLConnection..its upto you...